# Eager loading nested relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

For a school platform I would like to have list with all the students that are enrolled in a class with a certain schoolYear. In this list I would like to see the id, last_name, first_name and the class name of each student.

The Id + full name is no problem, but loading all the relationships and displaying the full class name with grade doesn't work.

my relationships are as following:

```
student -> hasMany -> Enrollments
-----------Enrollments -> belongsTo -> offering
--------------------------offering -> belongsTo -> schoolClasses
--------------------------offering -> belongsTo -> schoolyears
--------------------------------------schoolClass -> belongsTo -> grade
```

The class name consists out of the grade name + class name (e.g. Nursery 1 + A).

My EER is as following:

[image: EER diagram]

Currently I have this working:

[image: enter image Example here]

By doing this in my controller:

```
$students = Student::with('offerings.schoolClasses.grades')->get();
return view('student.overview', ['students' =>$students]);
```

and this in my view:

```
@foreach($students as $student)
<tr>
    <th scope="row">{{$student->id}}</th>
    <td>{{$student->first_name}}</td>
    <td>{{$student->last_name}}</td>
    <td>{{$student->offerings}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Could someone help me getting the final bits?

Comment: Your EER picture is missing `Student` model.

Comment: Students are users, sorry I didn't mention that. The student model is a model based on the user model but checks if a user is enrolled.

Comment: I see enrollement is a "join" table, or like Laravel call it, a "pivot" table. You could use help of [Laravel documentation on relationships Many to Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). You will find a similar case of yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong, the definition of my relationships in my models didn't contain a foreign key to reference on.

I had to add explicit foreign keys when referencing the relationship:

```
public function schoolClass(){
    return $this->belongsTo(SchoolClass::class,'school_class_id');
}

public function schoolyears(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Schoolyear::class,'schoolyear_id');
}
```

The `school_class_id` and `schoolyear_id` where necessary to load everything correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try like this:

```
$students = Student::with('offerings.schoolClasses.grades')
->with(array('offerings.schoolYears'=>function($query){
         $query->where('start', '=', $somedate)
     }))
->get();
```

and you can try this to show the grade:

```
{{$student->offerings->schoolClasses->grades->grade}}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, it seems that the schoolclasses and schoolyear return null. If I check my database it seems that the student in question has an enrollment linked to an offering with a class and grade. So normally this should work. Do you have any idea where it goes wrong?

Comment: you should show more of your code, like models and relations, like @Anwar_Nairi pointed, enrollments should by a pivot table of the many to many relation between users and offerings, if we see more code maybe can help you.

Comment: You are indeed correct, these relations were established, but as I found out I had to add the foreign key when referencing relationships. I get the hang of it now. Thank you both for helping me :)